# How can I reference a form when overriding a GET request in a class based view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I overrode the GET request function handler in this class based view. In my else statement, I need to pass, as context data, the form that the class naturally creates (if I had not overridden the GET function). How can I do that?

I did not create a form at forms.py to create a form for the Post model. I let the create class based view handle the form creation for me. So, how can I get this form and pass as context data.

The only way I can think of doing this is creating a function based view and avoid using this class based view in this circumstance.

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["title", "content", "payment_option", "price"]

    def get(self, request):
        card_set = BillingProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).card_set.all()
        if not card_set.exists():
            # The user does NOT have an inserted payment method.
            return redirect("/billing/payment-method?next=/post/new/")
        else:
            # The user DOES have an inserted payment method.
            form = "???"
            return render(request, "posting/post_form.html", {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method the class provides, which is `self.get_form()`.

But this actually wouldn't be the right thing to do. What your should really do is to delegate to the default implementation of `get` and let it do what it normally would.

```
    if not card_set.exists():
        # The user does NOT have an inserted payment method.
        return redirect("/billing/payment-method?next=/post/new/")
    else:
        return super().get(request)
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted.